# How can I test JDBC code using spring framework?

Tags: java, spring, testing, jdbc

I was looking through some of the framework for testing this and from what I can tell, it seems like there is a lot of depreciation. Most of the code seems to be pointing to this SimpleJdbcTemplate class which was depreciated as of Spring 3.1. Is there an alternative to using this when mocking database connections?

My goal is to be able to write test cases that do not depend on the existence of a database. I am working with Spring 3.1 and Java 7. The database I was given was a SQL database.

Comment: Hi @Kubunto, did you considered to use an in-memory database for your tests?

Comment: How would this work @gerardribas?

Comment: @NathanHughes, Sadly all I know is that it is a SQL database that I cannot manipulate directly in a meaningful way (such as create a new one or influence its structure)

Comment: @Kubunto see my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: if the sql you use is reasonably standards-compliant then an in-memory db is not out of the question. h2 bends over backward to work with oracle sql, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like **H2**. http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html

```
db.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
db.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test
db.username=
db.password=
db.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

or **HSQL**. http://hsqldb.org/

```
db.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
```

Comment: I was given a DB already and I do not control what kind of DB it is @Suvasis

Answer (score 0):

For speed up my tests on my DAO Layer implemented with Spring JDBC, I use an in-memory database.

If you are using maven these are the dependencies that you need:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
  <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

The first one is the embedded database and the second one is for spring test jars.

Well, I will introduce how I do the test and the configuration.

MyApplicationStandaloneConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@Profile("local")
@ComponentScan("cat.mypackages")
public class MyApplicationStandaloneConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DataSource myApplicationDataSource() throws NamingException {

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test");
        dataSource.setUsername("sa");
        dataSource.setPassword("");

        ResourceDatabasePopulator pop = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        pop.addScript(new ClassPathResource("sql/schema.sql"));
        pop.addScript(new ClassPathResource("sql/one_table_inserts.sql"));
        pop.addScript(new ClassPathResource("sql/another_table_inserts.sql"));
        return dataSource;
    }

}
```

Note that I annotated this @Profile as a local, this means that I can create multiple configuration files for different environments, for example, imagine that you want to run an integration tests against your development / qa / uat database.

See that I'm loading the schema.sql and some other sql scripts. This contains my schema for my tables to create and the inserts that I want to expect on my test cases.

And then it's easy, create a test case like that:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyApplicationStandaloneConfiguration.class)
@ActiveProfiles("local")
public class MyDaoTestCase {

    @Autowired
    private MyDao dao;

    @Test
    public void testFindId() {
        SomeDto dto = dao.findById(123);
        assertNotNull(dto);
        ...
    }

}
```

Hope it hepls!